# isZoomed() functionality is not working in my client code

Tags: windows, winapi, win32-process

i wanted to know whether mstsc(RDP) window maximized or not from my client application.
so i'm using :

IsZoomed(handle of mstsc); but i'm always getting zero as return value even if i maximized the window ?

How do i solve this problem ... ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IsZoomed` detects whether the window is maximized in the `WS_MAXIMIZED` sense, which means that it has a caption bar with a maximize button. But fullscreen apps don't work that way, which is why `IsZoomed` always reports "It is not maximized with a caption bar." You will have to use some alternate detection mechanism, like looking at the window dimensions.